# Changing class based on input change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect change on a select input and modify a the label class but it seems it does not change. Well, it does change, but only once and not when you change again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentPayment = $(".ty-payments-list li input:checked").attr("id");
    $(".ty-payments-list li").find('label.'+currentPayment).addClass('selected');

    $('.ty-payments-list input').change(function(){
        var newPayment = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".ty-payments-list li label.selected").removeClass('selected');
        $(".ty-payments-list li").find("label."+newPayment).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="ty-payments-list">                    
            <li class="ty-payments-list__item">
                <input id="payment_1" class="ty-payments-list__checkbox cm-select-payment" type="radio" name="payment_id" value="1" checked="checked" style="display:none;">
                <div class="ty-payments-list__item-group">
                    <label for="payment_1" class="payment_1 ty-payments-list__item-title">Card </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="ty-payments-list__item">
                <input id="payment_12" class="ty-payments-list__checkbox cm-select-payment" type="radio" name="payment_id" value="12" style="display:none;">
                <div class="ty-payments-list__item-group">
                    <label for="payment_12" class="payment_12 ty-payments-list__item-title"> PayPal</label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your code works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmjudw57/).

Comment: Even when you switch between then? works when i change once but then does not when i keep changing between the 2

Comment: @James _"works when i change once but then does not when i keep changing between the 2 "_ Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Ahh seems was the ajax reloaded page and loosing styles, i fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP commented that he fixed the problem after finding it was in Ajax-loaded content not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some odd browser issue? Have you tried finding the selected input explicitly again in the handler, and see if that behaves differently for you?

I.e. instead of

```
    var newPayment = $(this).attr("id");
```

try

```
    var newPayment = $(".ty-payments-list li input:checked").attr("id");
```

Comment: Post a jsfiddle or similar, as suggested above? And what browser/OS?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Thanks 'delighted', that was my thought too, but I need 50 rep to comment, which is now a little more difficult thanks to your downvote. :)

Comment: So close! ;) Looks like OP fixed his issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the solution, when you changed the payment method it reloaded the section via ajax so was always resetting what we was changing in the JS so this was my final solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentPayment = $(".ty-payments-list li input:checked").attr("id");
    $(".ty-payments-list li").find('label.'+currentPayment).addClass('selected');

    $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_12').click(function(){
        $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_1').removeClass('selected');
        $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_12').addClass('selected');
        $('.cm-checkout-place-order').text('Complete my order with PayPal');
    });

    $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_1').click(function(){
        $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_12').removeClass('selected');
        $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_1').addClass('selected');
        $('.cm-checkout-place-order').text('Complete my order');
    });
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings) {
    var currentPayment = $(".ty-payments-list li input:checked").attr("id");
    $(".ty-payments-list li").find('label.'+currentPayment).addClass('selected');

    $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_12').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_1').removeClass('selected');
            $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_12').addClass('selected');
            $('.cm-checkout-place-order').text('Complete my order with PayPal');
        }, 1000);
    });

    $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_1').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_12').removeClass('selected');
            $('.ty-payments-list li label.payment_1').addClass('selected');
            $('.cm-checkout-place-order').text('Complete my order');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```